# Running command on heroku console from a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to run a heroku console command from a rake task, so my approach is to try to do it all on one line.
Note that this works

> heroku run console
>   Rails.cache.clear

Here is my rake task:

```
task :setup_staging_env do
  sh "heroku run console Rails.cache.clear"
end
```

But this fails. So to simplify I tried just that command on the command line and get this:

```
heroku run console Rails.cache.clear
Running console Rails.cache.clear attached to terminal... up, run.1
You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for your Rails.cache.clear environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :log, :notify or :stderr at config/environments/Rails.cache.clear.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:156:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): (URI::InvalidURIError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:174:in `parse'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:628:in `parse'
from /app/config/initializers/resque.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:556:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /app/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

So how can I run this command from a rake task?

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily related to you running a heroku command from a rake task. The error message says that there's something breaking in your `config/initializers/resque.rb` on line 2. Have you double checked that the app actually starts properly?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am dealing with something very similar.